# Add to 12 but still wrapping(column nesting)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

This the output I want:
[image: This the output I want]

This is the output I am getting:
[image: This is the output I am getting]

As You can see the sub column adds to total of 12 columns but when i add a margin of 5px to container class the last container column wraps which i dont want and cant figure it out how to solve it.
As i am beginner with bootstrap so really appreciate all the help Thanx in adavance :)

```css
body{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
.container{
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
  padding: 0px;
}
.nav-col{
  background-color: #ABABAB;
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
}
.header{
  background-color: #E2E2E2;
  height: 20vh;
  max-height: 20vh;
  padding: 0px;
}
.content{
  background-color: #E2E2E2;
  height: 80vh;
  max-height: 80vh;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0 0px;
}
.p-0{
  padding:0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bootstrap form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4 nav-col">
     <div>hello</div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-7 p-0">
     <div class="col-md-12 header p-0"></div>
         <div class="col-md-4 content ">hello</div>
         <div class="col-md-4 content">hello</div>
         <div class="col-md-4 content">hello</div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the code with the bootstrap template you need

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
  padding: 0px;
}

.nav-col {
  background-color: #ABABAB;
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  background-color: #E2E2E2;
  height: 20vh;
  max-height: 20vh;
}

.content {
  background-color: #E2E2E2;
  height: 73vh;
  max-height: 73vh;
}

.top-buffer{
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Bootstrap form</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row gutter-small">
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div class="nav-col">hello</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-9">
        <div class="row gutter-small">
          <div class="col-xs-12"><div class="header"></div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row top-buffer gutter-small">
          <div class="col-xs-4"><div class="content"></div></div>
          <div class="col-xs-4"><div class="content"></div></div>
          <div class="col-xs-4"><div class="content"></div></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ok I just edit my code tell me if it's ok bro :) The trick was to move your content, header, nav-col class in child div of col-md

Comment: it did work but its overflowing if do overflow:hidden itll make it non-responsive which is not wat i want and thankx for replying this quickly man really apreaciate the help :) nd sorry if my questions are too stupid really new to front end

Comment: Ok i edit my code again. But not sure to have understood your question. Can you provide the responsive template you need ?

Comment: the first is image i added is the desired output i want which should be responsive also

Comment: yes I saw your template but do you want the same layout on smartphone ?

Comment: In this case you have to use col-xs

Comment: thanx it worked and one more when im in lg screen the scroll bar is still comming how to do hide that using overflow? property in css

Comment: I don't have scrollbar on Large screen :'(